# Set a form value as that of a UL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, html-lists

I am using a jQuery plugin called '[tagit](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/)'.

I know you can't post a UL, but how can I get around that?

Lets say that I have:

```
<ul name="addtags" id="addtags" class="addtags" placeholder="Tags">
     <li>Add your tags here</li>
</ul>

<input type="hidden" name="addtagsReal" />
```

When the form is submitted, I do validation with javascript. So I was thinking that, in my validation, I could simply set the hidden 'addtagsReal' input to that of the ul.

How can I do this with jQuery?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe the placeholder attribute is only available on input elements.

Comment: How do you want to post form data? Using php or using ajax? You can set data attribute to UL and validate in js.

Comment: sorry yeah meant to remove the placeholder. And posting using PHP, but ajax for validation. Ill have a bit of a delve through the plugin and see if it gives any information

Answer (score 0):

You essentially need a way to "serialize" the list, an older jquery plugin to do this is here:

[jQuery serialize list](https://github.com/botskonet/jquery.serialize-list)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var separator = ",";
var str = $('#addtags').children('li').map(function(i,el){
   return($(el).text()); 
}).get().join(separator);


$('input[name="addtagsReal"]').val(str);
```

And then you send your LIs separated by ´separator´, and explode them with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can make comma separated 'data' strings with simple concatenation and some jQuery tomfoolery. There are certainly better ways to do it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var sampleTags = ['c++', 'java', 'php'],
        eventTags = $('#eventTags');

    eventTags.tagit({
        availableTags: sampleTags,
        afterTagAdded: function(evt, ui) {
            updateTagInput();
        },
        afterTagRemoved: function(evt, ui) {
            updateTagInput();
        }

    });
});

function updateTagInput() {
    var $hidden = $('input[name=addtagsReal]'), 
        values = "";

    $('#eventTags').find('.tagit-label').each(function(i, item){
        values += $(item).text() + ', ';
    });

       // update the input and trim the final ', ' 
   $hidden.val(values.substr(0, values.length - 2 ));
}
```

**edit**: oops! Deleted the plunk, thought I was deleting a version of it! Sorry, not going to recreate it but it used the html from the Events portion of this page http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/examples.html

Comment: Thanks :) Ill look an implementing that now :)!